# Referring multiple names to the same entity

Tags: python, modeling, record-linkage, named-entity-recognition

I am working on the models of different product types and wish to generalize them to the same entity. For example, from the given list

```
Toshiba-A40C
Toshiba B30
Toshiba-Z40C411
Asus -X540
Asus R4
Dell XPS 15
Dell Inspiron 13
```

I would like to get a clean list of

```
Toshiba
Toshiba
Toshiba
Asus
Asus
Dell
Dell
```

Is there a programmatic way to get this one ? Is this called a record linkage? What are your recommendations ?

Comment: Index-Match or Vlookup in Excel could accomplish this simply.  R base code allows you to look up a value in a dataset (like the one you have above) given an input value.

Comment: Thank you @ERT  . What if the first word is misspelled such as Thoshiba- A40C. Is there a way we can generalize it to 'Toshiba' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that there are better solutions to this problem. I used a regular expression to match first space or dash and then cut the original list.

```
import re

example = """Toshiba-A40C
Toshiba B30
Toshiba-Z40C411
Asus -X540
Asus R4
Dell XPS 15
Dell Inspiron 13""".split('\n')

regular_exp = '(?: +)|(-)'

for i in range(len(example)):
    where = re.search(regular_exp, example[i]).span()
    example[i] = example[i][:where[0]]

print(example)
```